# WinRT CoInitialize in Python

Tags: python, windows, com, windows-runtime

I have the following simple code:

```
import winrt.windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer as DataTransfer

clipboard = DataTransfer.Clipboard
print(clipboard.clear())
```

And am getting this error, any idea how to fix?

```
print(clipboard.clear())
RuntimeError: CoInitialize has not been called.
```

Comment: pythoncom.CoInitialize() ?

Comment: @SimonMourier still same error, if I put it before the winrt import, it says cannot change thread mode after it is set

Comment: There seems to be issue with the way winrt/python initialize things: https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/690 . You can try to edit your winrt init py (something like C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\winrt\__init__.py) and comment the `_winrt.init_apartment()` line (and possibly add `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`) see if it works any better

Comment: @SimonMourier that worked (without adding ```pythoncom.CoInitialize()```), thanks a lot